# Uploading products from excel file

Tags: excel, import, e-commerce, product

I was wondering what is the best way of importing products into database.

Product names have unique sku's.

The Excel file may contain existing sku's.

One way of doing import is:

1. Read record from excel
2. Check sku for existence in database table
   if already exists, update it
   or
   if not found, insert it

Second way:
1. Read record from excel
2. Check sku for existence in database table
   if already exists, delete it   (will surely change the create_data, auto_id)
   or
   if not found, insert it

If I upload say 1000 records, then there will be 1000 x 2 (update/delete + insert) queries fired on database.

Is there any other efficient solution?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on database management system. Keywords: "Insert on duplicate key Update" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/insert-on-duplicate.html, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most performant way would be option 1. As Joe R already mentioned option 2 causes unnecessary database calls.

You could make it an option though, in a lot of cases deleting all products even is a probability.

You could have a DELETE or UPDATE option available for the one uploading the data. For example deleting would be favourable if you have a lot of excess data in the database that you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer option one, as that actually fits the requirements.

Option two is unnecessarily deleting rows.